# Unable to remove element/node using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml, elementtree

I have an issue with ElementTree that I can't quite figure out.  I've read all their documentation as well as all the information I could find on this forum.  I have a couple elements/nodes that I am trying to remove using ElementTree.  I don't get any errors with the following code, but when I look at the output file I wrote the changes to, the elements/nodes that I expected to be removed are still there.  I have a document that looks like this:

```
<data>
  <config>
    <script filename="test1.txt"></script>
    <documentation filename="test2.txt"></script>
  </config>
</data>
```

My code looks as follows:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree    
xmlTree = ElementTree.parse(os.path.join(sourcePath, "test.xml"))
xmlRoot = xmlTree.getroot()
for doc in xmlRoot.findall('documentation'):
     xmlRoot.remove(doc)

xmlTree.write(os.path.join(sourcePath, "testTWO.xml"))
```

The result is I get the following document:

```
<data>
  <config>
    <script filename="test1.txt" />
    <documentation filename="test2.txt" />
  </config>
</data>
```

What I need is something more like this.  I am not stuck using ElementTree. If there is a better solution with lxml or some other library, I am all ears.  I know ElementTree can be a little bit of a pain at times.

```
<data>
  <config>
  </config>
</data>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xmlRoot.findall('documentation')` in your code didn't find anything, because  `<documentation>` isn't direct child of the root element `<data>`. It is actually direct child of `<config>` :

> "Element.findall() finds only elements with a tag which are direct children of the current element". [[19.7.1.3. Finding interesting elements](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements)]

This is one possible way to remove all children of `<config>` using `findall()` given sample XML you posted (and assuming that the actual XML has `<documentation>` element closed with proper closing tag instead of closed with `</script>`) :

```
......
config = xmlRoot.find('config')

# find all children of config
for doc in config.findall('*'):
    config.remove(doc)
    # print just to make sure the element to be removed is correct
    print ElementTree.tostring(doc)
......
```

Comment: Thank you for the example.  I can see where I went wrong based on what you provided.  However, in the initial XML example I just put a couple elements under **<config>**.  I only want to remove the **<script>** and <documentation> elements and keep everything else.  So I added the following code.  The documentation node gets deleted but not the script.  When I **print ElementTree.tostring()** I see that it properly finds the **<script>** and **<documentation>** elements.

Comment: Here is the code:

            # Remove the 'documentation' and 'script' tags from test.xml

            if documentation is None:
                pass
            else:
                config = xmlRoot.find('config')
                for doc in config.findall('documentation'):
                    config.remove(doc)
                    print ElementTree.tostring(doc)

Comment: if script is None:
                pass
            else:
                config = xmlRoot.find('config')
                for script in config.findall('script'):
                    config.remove
                    print ElementTree.tostring(script)

            xmlTree.write(os.path.join(sourcePath, "driverTWO.xml"))

Comment: Nevermind.  I forgot to pass in the variable to config.remove.  Added config.remove(script) and it works fine.

Comment: I would like to point out that you *can* use `findall` to find elements anywhere in an XML tree (not just direct children). `findall(".//documentation")` is an example. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax.

Comment: @mzjn Agreed, given supported XPath expression, `findall()` can find elements anywhere in accordance to the XPath. Thought  that part of the documentation I quoted meant specifically in the context when `findall()` given element name as argument? Good point anyway, thanks